# Incredible lag for UI Sortable

Tags: jquery-ui

I've built a system that uses jQuery Sortable; however, there is a huge lag for moving an element (we are talking at about 8 seconds to move an element).

On that page, we have about 2000 draggable items/pockets that can receive things, but no element has hidden things (as I've read that can cause lag) and there's no real use of CSS3.

Here's an example of one element that would be dragged:

```
<div data-runtime="30" data-name="1600 Penn" data-color="#00B3FF" data-id="751" class="pocket color2" style="">
    <h4 style="">1600 Penn</h4>
    <p>NBC</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="pocket_actions">
        <div class="timer timer1" data-timered="1" data-id="751"></div>
        <div class="public onpublic" data-id="751"></div>
        <div data-id="751" class="note"></div>
        <a style="float:left;" class="edit fancybox.iframe" href="schedule.php?action=edit&amp;id=751">
            <img src="includes/images/edit.png">
        </a>
        <div class="delete" data-id="751"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to decrease this lag? Even picking up an item takes about 2 seconds, which is simply crazy!

Comment: You have **2000** draggable items and you're wondering why it's slow?

Comment: Yeah, it'snot 200k, with 4gb Latest MBP i'd suspect that it's not a memory problem, so i'm looking at possible reasons